# How to use Ray library for parallelization in code repository of the Palantir?

Tags: python, ray

while using ray.get() command, I am getting issue. Can anyone help?
I was trying the same in jupyter notebook parallelization using ray. It is working good. But is should execute in the same way in code repo of Palantir, function.remote is working but unable to fetch the output as ray.get() is not working.